# How to Specify Product Quantity Of Multiple Options in Opencart

Tags: opencart, inventory-management

I am having a little but pretty serious problem with opencart inventory control.

Lets say I have a Shirt with 3 colors (Red, Black, White) and 3 sizes (S, M, L) and want to specify quantity for each size and color so, when Red in S is sold old, it should only deduct 1 from Red and not the whole stock/option.

I hope you got my point.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in the way you described with OpenCart out of the box.  You'll either need a third party extension or you need to structure your options explicitly like:

```
Red S
Red M
Red L
Black S
Black M
Black L
White S
White M
White L
```

This way you can specify stock amounts for each one and disable them as needed when out of stock.

Comment: This should be the core feature of the cart. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: Maybe you should ask for a refund